# Getting element in PHP - PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom

Can you help me with the resolution below?
I have the following code in html:

```
<div class="return-form">
                                <div class="two_cols">
                                    <div class="first_col">
                                        <label for="namesinger">Name:</label> </div>
                                    <div class="second_col">
                                        <p id="name">Axl Rose</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I am using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser library and I would like to display only the name "Axl Rose" on the screen.

```
echo ($ name)
```

expected exit
Axl Rose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can extract the data

```
<?php
// Load the HTML
$html = str_get_html('<div class="return-form">
                                <div class="two_cols">
                                    <div class="first_col">
                                        <label for="namesinger">Name:</label> </div>
                                    <div class="second_col">
                                        <p id="name">Axl Rose</p>
                                    </div>
                                </di');

// Locate the date via div ID and display
echo $html->find('p[id=name]', 0)->plaintext;
?>
```

For more details [Read this](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)

Comment: `'div[id=name]'` should be `'p[id=name]'` because  it's `<p id="name">Axl Rose</p>`.